# I2C read() lost 1 bit

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, i2c, iio

I try to use I2C to read data from ADS1110, the address of ADS1110 is seven bits, which is `1001 000`. Writing data can only change the configuration register, which is done in the form of address + configuration. Reading data returns 3 bytes of data, which are high-order bytes data, low-order bytes data, and configuration. The default configuration of ADS1110 is 0x8C, and the highest bit is generally 0 in continuous mode, indicating that the converted data is the latest. I use read() and write() to implement I2C reading, the code is as follows:

```c
#define NUMS 10
char readbuf[NUMS];

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // int file = i2c_init("/dev/i2c-0", 0x48);
    int file = open("/dev/i2c-0", O_RDWR);
    int addr = 0b01001000;

    if (file < 0) {
        printf("openfile error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, addr) < 0) {
        printf("ioctl error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Debug Gain 1
    readbuf[0] = 0x0C;

    if (write(file, readbuf, 1) != 1) {
        printf("write error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (read(file, readbuf, 3) != 3) {
        printf("read error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("%x %x %x\n", readbuf[0] & 0xff, readbuf[1] & 0xff, readbuf[2] & 0xff);

    close(file);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Here I configure the ADS1110 as 0x0C, which means that I am reading in continuous mode, and the gain of the ADC is 1 times, and the specified reading rate is 15sps, that is, I can read 2.048V (7FFF) with 16-bit accuracy enter. But when my input is less than 1.024V, the read result is correct; when the data is greater than 1.024V, `D14` should be 1, but I get a result of 0. For example, when the input is 1.5V, the output should is `5D XX (0101)`, but I only get `1D XX (0001)`. But except for D14, the values ​​of all registers including Config are correct. The result displayed by the oscilloscope is shown in the following figure:

[image: pic1]

Comment: Since you can see on your scope trace that the signal is low when it should be high, the software is working correctly and so there is nothing you can ask about on stack overflow.  I suggest that you post the same question on electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: For what it's worth it looks to me like your correct target is releasing SDA and something else on the bus is pulling the signal low.  When you post on electronics include a schematic of what else is on the bus.

Comment: Is it Linux? Why don't you use the driver in kernel and communicate with it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an NS2009 on the board, and the address conflicts with the ADS1110.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).